# Rails order by a field in parent belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, sorting

I have three models in my Rails app, `User`, `Number`, and `Message`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :numbers
  has_many :messages, through: :numbers
end

class Number < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :messages
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :number
end
```

`Number` migration file has:

```
t.string :digits, index: true # Example: '14051234567' (no + sign)
```

In my controller:

```
sort_mode = # asc or desc
@messages = current_user.messages.order(???)
```

The thing is that I want to sort those messages by **their numbers' digits**.

How to do that **dynamically** (depending on sort_mode)?

**EDIT:**

```
sort_mode = 'asc'
@messages = current_user.messages.includes(:number)
order = { number: { digits: sort_mode } }
@messages = @messages.order(order)
```

^ Doesn't work. Second argument must be a *direction*.

**Also**, `order('number.digits': sort_mode)` throws:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: messages.number.digits: SELECT  "messages".* FROM "messages" INNER JOIN "numbers" ON "messages"."number_id" = "numbers"."id" WHERE "numbers"."user_id" = ?  ORDER BY "messages"."number.digits" ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'll need to use `includes`.  Try:

```
@messages = current_user.messages.includes(:number).order('numbers.digits ASC')
```

Comment: Sorry, ActiveRecord was building the wrong SQL clause for order.  Try `'numbers.digits ASC'` instead.  You could modify your `sort_mode` variable to be a string in this format and then use that instead.

Comment: working fine for me, thank you.